# Mac client can't resolve Windows Home Server name

Tags: windows, svn, macos, networking, netbios

I think this is more a Mac networking configuration issue than anything else, but am not sure.

I have Subversion set up on my Windows Home Server machine (similar to this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/RunningASubversionServerOffYourWindowsHomeServer.aspx).  This setup has been working for me for months, using Windows clients.

Now I'm trying to add a Mac client, and it can't resolve the network name of my WHS server.  If I open a terminal window on the mac, and attempt to ping or use nslookup, I get an error that it can't find the server.  On the PC side, I can ping, but nslookup doesn't resolve the name, so I'm assuming that PC's ping is resolving the name as a NetBios name.

I've found a number of articles online that explain how to set up default suffixes based on Windows domains, but the Windows Home Server doesn't establish a domain by default.  (It's in workgroup mode.)

Anyone have any suggestions or pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and easy way to get this working would be to add an entry to your host file on the MAC.  You can find the file in /etc/hosts

Edit the file and add an entry at the end as follows:

```
<ip address>  <hostname>
```

example:

69.59.196.211   www.stackoverflow.com

That is the way that I would go, and they mention using the host file in the article you posted.  More info on editing the hostfile of different machines can be found here:

http://practice.chatserve.com/hosts.html

Comment: Excellent.  I don't know why this didn't occur to me -- I use the hosts file all the time on my windows machines.  While there may be a canonically more "proper" solution, this is just right for my needs.  Thanks much.